# Blank screen after dismissing UIModalPresentationCurrentContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I know there are other questions that address this, but none of the other solutions will work for this situation.

I have a `UITabBarController` that contains a `UINavigationController` as a tab root.

I'm creating another `UINavigationController`, with a `UIViewController` as its root view controller, and presenting it modally with `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. The `UINavigationController` that presented this one sets `definesPresentationContext` to `YES`.

I change tabs and come back to the first tab. Then, I dismiss that `UINavigationController`, and the screen turns white (I think that's because the `UITabBarController` has a white background.)

Other questions suggest using `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`. And, yes, that does solve the white screen issue. But I can't use that because `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` aren't called on the presenting view controller. I have code that can ONLY be run from those places. So, `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` is a no-go.

I also can't use `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` or `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` because I have to display the Tab Bar while presenting modal window.

I will either have to use `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` and somehow figure out a way to trigger `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, or I need to use `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` and fix the blank screen issue.

Can anyone offer any advice? I'm banging my head on my desk and am about to break something... >:(

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem? I am having the same right now...

Comment: I'm looking at my code now, and I don't think I ever found a fix for this.

According to the comments in my code, I had read that it was a bug in UIKit itself. Which unfortunately means that there's very little, if not nothing, that we can do. But it looks like I didn't copy down a link to that, so I don't know what I read that convinced me of this.

What I ended up doing in my code was change these instances to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`. That also meant that I couldn't show the tab bar like I wanted to, but that was the only thing I could think of.

Comment: Maybe you'll have better luck than I did with this. If you do happen to find an actual solution to this, I'd love to hear it. Cheers!